# Call a custom function when a third party javascript async function completes its execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I have a scenario where I would like my function to be executed after a particular 3rd party js function completes its execution.

I can't edit the source of `loadOne` however I could add/override my `newLoadOne` as on click listener. So I can execute the `loadOne` on its behalf and execute my code with the data it returns.

Right now, my `newLoadOne` prints *console.log* before the `loadOne` method's async callback return.

HTML

```
<select id="option1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<select id="option2">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>

<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

JavaScript

```
function loadOne(){
    someAsyncXhrMethod(with_its_own_parameters);//its own xhr method with aync callbacks 
}


function newLoadOne(){

    (function(){loadOne(); console.log('done');}());
}

function optionschanged(){
    console.log('options changed');
}

function bEvents(){
    $('#option1').change(optionschanged);
    $('#option2').change(optionschanged);
    $('#submit').bind('click', newLoadOne); //this is where i replace the call to loadOne with my newLoadOne
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('ready');
    bEvents();

});
```

here is the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/palaniraja/pERup/3/) -  **Note:** $.ajax call in the source is to explain the method `loadOne` has some async callbacks. So `$(document).ajaxComplete` is not the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately if the author of the library hasn't made this possible then there's nothing you can do about it (except bug them to fix their mistake). But why can't you edit the source?

Comment: It is 3rd party source code, I couldn't have access to it.

Comment: We'd need to know more about the original `loadone` works i think... To see if there is something we can hook in to...

Comment: Actually...why can't you use ajaxComplete?

Comment: @Jivings ajaxComplete works only if the 3rd party method uses jquery in my case it is not.

Comment: If the subject function does not return a promise and the asych operation is not jQuery.ajax, then you are very very stuck. I'm not saying impossible, but one would need to know a lot more before being able to advise.

Answer (score 2):

You have no real choice but to **poll** to see if the async method has completed. Presumably it does something that changes a state which is visible to you that you can poll for (we'll call that routine `check_some_async_xhr_method_completed`), at some appropriate frequency.

```
function newLoadOne () {
    loadOne (); 
    check_completion (function (completed) {
        console.log (completed ? 'done' : 'never finished');
    });
}

function check_completion (callback) {
    var number_of_tries = 20;
    var timer = setInterval (
        function () {
            if (check_some_async_xhr_method_completed ()) {
                clearInterval (timer);
                callback (true);
            } else if (!number_of_tries--) {
                clearInterval (timer);
                callback (false);
            }
        },       
        500
    );
}
```

Or, if you would prefer to use promises:

```
function newLoadOne () {
    loadOne (); 
    check_completion ().then (
        function () {console.log ('done'),
        function () {console.log ('never finished')
    );
}    

function check_completion () {
    var promise = Promise.new();
    var number_of_tries = 20;
    var timer = setInterval (
        function () {
            if (check_some_async_xhr_method_completed ()) {
                clearInterval (timer);
                p.fulfill ();
            } else if(!number_of_tries--) {
                clearInterval (timer);
                p.reject ();
            }
        },       
        500
    );
    return promise;
}
```

Or, the `when` library already has a routine which handles polling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I xhr method in question is actually updating the list (html select tag) with new options, I had to reformat the display string of each options, issue with Set/clear Interval routine is people will notice the change in anyway (if xhr completed before the next interval call. Handling options update is definitely different SO question. And DOMSubtreeModified is deferred :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like this would work...

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
  if ( settings.url === "the/url/that/loadone/uses" ) {
    // do your callback here
  }
});
```

*Sorry, this only works when the request is made using jQuery.*

Comment: Will that work? He's not using the jQuery ajax functionality so will this handler ever be called? Does it actually apply to non-jquery XMLHTTPRequests?

Comment: @prodigitalson I actually have no idea and can't find a reference that specifies. I'll mock up a demo.